# Getting Changes from one branch to other without changing master

Tags: git, branching-and-merging

I would like to do something as below;

Person A suppose working on branch A branched out of a master.
Person B suppose working on branch B branched out of a master.

Now how to merge changes from branch A to branch B without merging any of the branches to Master. (These are experimental branches say working on same files but different functionalities. So quite often, A's changes are required in B and vice versa. But none of them can be merged to Master due to they being experimental).

So this is what I was looking for: (See added picture)[image]

Please provide a solution on how to do this?

Answer (score 0):

I would go to BranchB then do the following:

```
    git merge branchA --no-commit
```

From the doc: [git merge](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-merge)

> Incorporates changes from the named commits (since the time their histories diverged from the current branch) into the current branch. This command is used by git pull to incorporate changes from another repository and can be used by hand to merge changes from one branch into another.
>
> With --no-commit perform the merge and stop just before creating a merge commit, to give the user a chance to inspect and further tweak the merge result before committing.

Comment: Wow, that helped immediately. Thanks for the prompt reply!

Answer (score 0):

Go to branch a and do the following 
    `git merge --no-ff branchB`

Comment: What does " --no-ff " flag do if you would like to explain?

Comment: The `--no-ff` flag prevents git merge from executing a "fast-forward" if it detects that your current HEAD is an ancestor of the commit you're trying to merge. A fast-forward is when, instead of constructing a merge commit, git just moves your branch pointer to point at the incoming commit. This commonly occurs when doing a `git pull` without any local changes.